# How to reconnect to process stopped by using ctrl-a x in Screen?

Tags: linux, r, gnu-screen

In linux I was using the screen software and I was opening to R programming language editor. When writing I pressed intentionally on ctrl-a x and the go out from R.

but when running `ps -la` I can see that R is still running.

```
ps -la
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 R   548  2427 32324  0  77   0 - 15875 -      pts/1    00:00:00 ps
0 T   548  4109 31462  3  75   0 - 2100701 finish pts/5  10:29:25 R
```

but it is marked with finish, is it possible to reconnect to it?

I have tried to use this command to send some text to it

```
echo 'save.image()' > /proc/4109/fd/0
```

but it didn't work. 
actually I have tried to write to the STDIN, in fact it works but I need to \n to it, when I send it only consider it as a text no a command, so I will get in the R editor this value

```
>save.image()
```

but the return caret is not taken into consideration.

Do any one have a solution for that, the data that I am manipulating is sensitive and don't want re-do all the scripting again because it needs days to execute and analyze the data.

Comment: "Ctrl+a x" locks the screen session per default!? (Enter user password to unlock)

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like you inadvertently put the R process in the background. Try reattaching to your screen session, go the the shell/window where it was, and type `fg` to bring it to the foreground again.

Comment: hehe, I tried `fg`, but unfortunatly the process stoped I got  `R Terminated`